# cannot access archive: No such file or library

Tags: command-line, drivers, wireless, files

```
zenon@zenon-vostro2510:~$ sudo dpkg -i file:///home/zenon/Desktop/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for zenon: 
dpkg: error processing archive file:///home/zenon/Desktop/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 file:///home/zenon/Desktop/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb
```

Every answer I've found for similar problems says that the file path was wrong and says to copy/paste the file path. That's what I did; this file path is correct. The file exists. I'm trying to work through [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access) to get my WiFi adapter working. How can I fix this error?

After removing `file://`, I get this error, and frankly I can't figure out what to do with it.

```
zenon@zenon-vostro2510:~$ sudo dpkg -i /home/zenon/Desktop/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for zenon: 
(Reading database ... 172999 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bcmwl-kernel-source:
 bcmwl-kernel-source depends on dkms; however:
  Package dkms is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the file `/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl` from my Ubuntu live USB, as [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access) said to do. I didn't realize it worked until I rebooted. Now I can access the Internet without any problems. Thanks to both of you who answered!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're copying that file path from Chrome or something (`file://` is how Chrome accesses the local filesystem).

Remove the `file://` part, so you just have `/home/zenon/....` and try again.

Comment: I think it's a local filesystem URI maybe, you can use the same format in Subversion

Comment: @Arronical I just know it from Chrome, so I used that as an example.

Comment: I copied and pasted the file from the file browser. I'll try that when I get a chance to

Comment: See new results in original question

Comment: @Zenon just run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @Zacharee1 It says that bcmwl-kernel-source will be removed and that nothing will be upgraded or installed, then asks me to confirm. Is this what it's supposed to do?

Comment: @Zenon is this 16.10?

Comment: @Zacharee1 16.04. Should I get 16.10 instead?

Comment: @Zenon no, I was thinking that the DEB you have might not work on 16.10. Although now, I'm not exactly sure why you don't just use `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I'm completely new to this; I didn't know that command. I ran that command. It says that bcmwl-kernel source is already installed, but that it has unmet dependencies. It said: `bcmwl-kernel-source : Depends: dkms, but it is not installable` Then is suggests running `apt-get -f install`, which is what I did before.

Comment: Purge it and try reinstalling (`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`. When did you last run `sudo apt-get update`? What is the output of `sudo apt-get install dkms`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that dpkg does not handle the URI form of the file that you're specifing. Try simply

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/zenon/Desktop/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb
```